# Why can't I get Ubuntu to sync with iOS 5.1?

Tags: iphone

I have an iPhone and I want to switch completely to Ubuntu. The problem is I can't get libmobile to work. It looks like it synced but the music or video doesn't show up on the phone. I also can't use sbmanager. Am I just a noob that can't figure this out?

Comment: Have you checked this http://askubuntu.com/questions/90197/what-software-is-available-for-ipod-synchronization ?

Answer (score 1):

I've found the easiest way to get my iPad to work on Ubuntu is to install iTunes in a Windows XP guest in Virtual Box.

There are other solutions like libimobiledevice (http://libimobiledevice.org/) but I've never managed to get it to work, and it appears that iOS updates may occasionally break compatibility.

Answer (score 0):

Get wine and install itunes ;)

Comment: Does it really work?

Comment: I have had 0 luck with iTunes, for many reasons. The program itself kinda craps out, and the iDevice isn't recognized even if the program (kind of) works.

Comment: Wine only works properly with older versions of iTunes. Get an Android device it is easier, unfortunately Apple does not want anyone to use their devices unless you use iTunes in Win or MAC. So why support them and purchase their products? You could try; Install Windows in a VM and share your music folder with the VM. There may be a solution using Google Play Music (USA only at the moment): http://askubuntu.com/questions/129097/how-do-i-sync-iphone-4-in-rhythmbox

Answer (score 0):

The answer is, you simply cannot, yet.

The library that Rhythmbox (and others) use to do this does not yet support the newer database version. If your iOS device has recently been updated, then you simply need to wait for libimobiledevice to be updated.

So, yes. Your best bet would be to use vmware or VirtualBox.