# How do I sync iPhone 4 in rhythmbox?

Tags: rhythmbox, iphone

I am using Ubuntu 12.04 and I have a iPhone 4 with iOS 5.1 that I just recently jailbroke. I was wondering if there was anyway that I can sync my music to my iPhone?

Answer (score 1):

Ubuntu has never been iPhone friendly. Your best bet is to install VirtualBox with Windows XP and install iTunes.

Comment: To connect a USB device to a VirtualBox VM requires the proprietary extensions for VirtualBox (which are available at no charge). You may want to expand this answer to explain this, and how to install them.

Answer (score 1):

I'm using Ubuntu 12.04 and syncing music to my iPhone through Google Play Music.  It's working very well.  Google Play has an Ubuntu music manager you can download at https://play.google.com/music/listen#manager_pl.  Using this application, I uploaded my entire iTunes library (up to 20,000 songs are free).  Then I installed the "Melodies" app on my iPhone to stream my music.  I like this app because it lets you save songs to your iPhone for offline listening.  Tip: Newer iTunes songs (.m4a files) are DRM-free, so they can be easily uploaded to Google Play.  Older iTunes songs (.m4p files) have DRM encoding and have to be converted first.  To make the conversion, I burned these songs to a CD using iTunes (be sure to check "Include CD Text") and then imported them back into iTunes.  There are other options to convert songs, but this was the easiest since I didn't have very many.

Comment: ... I suppose this would work in the USA - doesnt work for the rest of the world which doesnt have access to google play music :(

Comment: This solution is great! Thanks for pointing it out.

Answer (score 0):

There is a library called `libimobiledevice` meant for this but it is supported upto 11.04
But you can try installing the older packages to try if it works(these are packages for 32 bit)

```
sudo apt-get install libgpod-common libgpod4 libimobiledevice1 libplist1 libusbmuxd1 usbmuxd
```