# how to transfer music to iphone 4?

Tags: 13.10, rhythmbox, iphone, ios

I'm using Ubuntu 13.10 and I updated my iPhone 4's iOS to 7.0.4 (NOT Jail-broken) but I can't sync music using rhythmbox or any other tool, although my iPhone is detected when I plug it (new windows opens contains folders and files) but Rhythmbox doesn't find it.

I've searched every possible link or tool or blog and nothing seems to work, but this thing is driving me crazy.

please help.

Comment: Have you searched through askubuntu before posting? How about: http://askubuntu.com/questions/129097/how-do-i-sync-iphone-4-in-rhythmbox?rq=1 or http://askubuntu.com/questions/144270/cant-copy-my-music-from-rhythmbox-to-my-iphone?rq=1

Answer (score 1):

i have been through this nightmare too, with little help. I have an Ipod 4g. The only way I was really able to sync things up was to install virtual box, and then run Itunes through that. Using Itunes with Wine wasnt working at all. Hope this works for you!