# Rhythm box crashes when I plug in my iphone

Tags: rhythmbox, iphone, itunes

I've just downloaded ubuntu as a swap from mint. I heard it was easier to sync your iphone with ubuntu however, everytime I open rhythm box it crashes as soon as i plug my phone in?

any ideas? (except to stop using apple products of course!)

Cheers!

Comment: There are some suggestions [here](http://askubuntu.com/questions/129097/how-do-i-sync-iphone-4-in-rhythmbox).

Comment: I have the same problem

Comment: Try once connecting to Amarok. Believe it or not, it helped repair my Ipod once.. I hope it won't atleast crash.. :-) YOu can simply install amarok by typing sudo apt-get install amarok

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and I tried the steps listed below and it worked great!

[How to allow iOS 7 iPhone to sync? "Trust this computer" appears endlessly](https://askubuntu.com/questions/336112/how-to-allow-ios-7-iphone-to-sync-trust-this-computer-appears-endlessly)